# Updating QR decomposition for geometrically similar least squares problem

Tags: linear-solver, least-squares, qr

Let's say we have a weighted least squares problem under the same matrix $A$ such that,

$$\hat{x} := \arg \min_x ||A x - b||_{W_1}$$ where $|| \cdot ||_{W_1}$ is the Euclidean norm weighted by diagonal elements in $W_1$. We can solve this easily by performing a $QR$ decomposition of $W^{1/2}_1 A$ together with $W^{1/2}_1 b$ using standard software.

Given this, is there an approach to re-use the previous QR decomposition to solve a similar weighted least square problems under the same $A$, such that
$$\hat{z} := \arg \min_z ||A z - c||_{W_2}$$
if we can bound $||c - b||$ and $||W_1 - W_2||_F$?

The motivation for this, is to see if there are faster means of iterative re-weighted least squares to solve generalized inverse problems, rather than re-computing a complete $QR$ decomposition at each step.

My gut tells me that there is no easy way to re-use a $QR$, no matter the bound, as this would make too many related problems easy to solve (and thus folks would already be talking about it). Nature is uncaring in that way.

Comment: How large is your $A$ matrix?  Is it sparse?

Comment: Not necessarily large. $n \times p$ for $n \approx 1000$ and $p \approx 25$ (guestimates). Not sparse in general.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps only some values change, in which case you might be able to make use of the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to make a cheap rank-k update, given that
$$\hat{z} = \arg \min_z ||A z - c||_{W}$$
has the solution
$$\hat{z} =  (A^TWA)^{-1}A^TWc$$

Comment: Unfortunately in OP's problem, iteratively reweighted least squares, W is a diagonal matrix all of whose entries change at each step. They might change by very little when close to convergence, though.